# Is it possible to use ID tag to change css content

Tags: html, css

Is there a way on taking the ID's from html

**example**:

```
 id="title1"
```

so it takes whats in it to display in the content: section in the css.

```
    <table class="layout display responsive-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="th" id="title1">Title12</th>
                <th class="th">Title2</th>
                <th class="th">Title3</th>
                <th class="th">Title4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>


table.responsive-table td:nth-child(1):before {
        content: use id here;
    }
    table.responsive-table td:nth-child(2):before {
        content: 'Title 2';
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes using the attr() function.

```css
table.responsive-table td:nth-child(1):before {
  content: attr(id);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can take this via jquery. Just try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#title1").text();
})
```

Comment: While your post may answer the question, please try to refrain from posting answers that use a different language from what the original post uses or is tagged with.